# PHP trying to send a success message and then redirect user to another page

Tags: php, authentication, header

This is a login validation page, once It has validated the users details I want it to direct the user the the "account.php" page, all the validation works fine but the user just doesn't get redirected to the account page.

```
<?php   
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 

if($_SESSION['loggedin'] = true) {
    session_destroy();
}

if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    echo("ERROR|Please fill out all of the fields.");
} else {    
    $file = fopen("Users.csv","r");
    while(! feof($file)) {
        $rows = fgetcsv($file);
        if (($rows[1] == $username) && ($rows[4] == $password)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION["username"] = $rows[1];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $rows[2];
            $_SESSION["dateOfBirth"] = $rows[3];
            $_SESSION["password"] = $rows[4];
            $_SESSION["userScore"] = $rows[5];

            echo("SUCCESS|Logging In as " . $username);
            header('Location: ../account.php');
            exit();
        } 
    }
    echo("ERROR|Incorrect Username or Password.");
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing some HTML to browser, so, its not redirecting.

Remove

```
echo("SUCCESS|Logging In as " . $username);
```

Or, add

`ob_start()` in your file at the beginning.

This will store all output values in a buffer and will cause redirection to occur.

Comment: It still doesn't redirect me though

Comment: To clarify, you cannot redirect using a header after you have already sent some content to the browser. If you definitely want them to see the message and then be redirected, you can output a meta refresh tag in the head of the html like so: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />` but honestly, the user doesn't need to see that page and will b used to getting logged in instantly

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a header redirect once you've echoed out some HTML onto the page. You should be receiving an error like the below until you remove the echoed HTML.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of displaying the message on the screen you can use an alert box using javascript and then the user can be redirected to the other page. I hope if you want that user view the message, this would serve the purpose.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Successful login');";
echo "</script>";
```